# Coffeescript calling function inside jQuery docment.ready

Tags: jquery, testing, coffeescript, jasmine

Jasmine Test:

```
describe 'Toolbar', ->
  beforeEach ->
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "../spec/javascript/fixtures"
    loadFixtures("canvas_fixture.html")

  describe 'Rectangle Button Click', ->
    it 'adds the selected class to rectangle button', ->
      toolbar = new Toolbar()
      expect(toolbar).toBeDefined
      console.log $('#rectangle')
      toolbar.rectangle
      expect($('#rectangle').hasClass("selected")).toBeTruthy()
      console.log $('#rectangle')
```

Class:

```
class window.Toolbar
  jQuery ->
    rectangle: $('#rectangle').click ->
      $('#toolbar button').removeClass("selected")
      $('#rectangle').addClass("selected")
```

This test is failing for me as the selected class is not being added to the fixture, and I think I'm not calling the function correctly.  How do I call the

> $('#rectangle').click

function in my test?  Thanks.

Comment: Start by looking at the generated JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the whole context, but some things I see:

- `toolbar.rectangle` in your test is not calling a function, you need to say `toolbar.rectangle()` to actually call it
- Your class as written is not defining a method on the Toolbar class, you should write something like this:

  ```
  class Toolbar
    rectangle: ->
      $('#rectangle').click ->
        $('#toolbar button').removeClass("selected")
        $('#rectangle').addClass("selected")
  ```
- When you write this `$('#rectangle').click -> ...`, you are defining an event handler that will get called when you click in `#rectangle`. If you want to have it have action immediately (i.e. when you call `toolbar.rectangle()`, you need something like this:

  ```
  class Toolbar
    rectangle: ->
      $('#toolbar button').removeClass("selected")
      $('#rectangle').addClass("selected")
  ```

Of course, you need to make sure all this happens after the page loads correctly, not familiar with Jasmine to say whether that will happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It was very helpful.  I'm hoping someone who has used jasmine before can also add some information because I still can't call the rectangle method in the test even if I use toolbar.rectangle()

Comment: Just downloaded Jasmine, made a spec as per the above, please go here for the complete test that works for me (in a browser, not from a local file system): https://github.com/icyrockcom/so7815109-jasmine-coffeescript